# Pass props down to scenes and modify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Building an app using React Native and the individual scenes are working great, really happy with it.

However now I'm looking at introducing some "global" state, so for instance to check if a user has an active session and if so add their data to some state which is shared (or passed) to the rest of the app.

I'm just not 100% where to put this code and where I'd store this data so the individual scenes can access (and also just as importantly - modify) this data?

I've had a stab at adding a prop to the `<Navigator />`, like so:

```
<Navigator user={this.getUser()} />
```

Which is then passed as a prop to `<SomeScene navigator={navigator} />` but this doesn't feel right, and I can't figure out how to then modify a prop of `navigator` (say a `user` property changes) then have these changes filter back up to the main `<Navigator />`.

From searching around I've seen Flux and React Router mentioned, but can't find an example of what I'm trying to do so was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using a Flux in your APP ?

Comment: @DhavalPatel Not yet - like I said, I can't find an example of what I'm trying to do so if you have one, please share!

Comment: so just See my answer I am going to answer your question

Comment: @DhavalPatel Ok, thanks.

Comment: Mike:is it useful for your question ?

Comment: @DhavalPatel Sort of, I'm just trying it out now and will mark as correct if it works. It would help it you'd give an example of a component using this and installation instructions (got these now, though).

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve using `Flux`, let me explain me with Flux, Flux is pattern which have Store and you can use the Store to store the Variable value here I am cover your example you want to store user information and want to access on each and every component for that your store contains two method one is for set User information and second one is for get the user information.

First you have to install the two module for this using below mentioned command

**npm install events underscore --save**

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var _ = require('underscore');

var _user;

// Extend UserStore with EventEmitter to add eventing capabilities
var UserStore = _.extend({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {


    getUserInfo: function() {
        return _user;
    },
    setUserInfo: function(user) {
        _user=user;
    }
});
module.exports=UserStore;
```

now you can use it this Store from any of your component like

```
var UserStore=require('./UserStore');
```

and set and get the userinfor from anywhere in your application like to set

```
UserStore.setUserInfo(user);
var user=UserStore.getUserInfo();
```

Comment: Is this just installed by `npm install events underscore --save`?

Comment: So every time I need to get a user's info I call `UserStore.getUserInfo()`, rather than doing `this.setState({ user: UserStore.getUserInfo() });`?

Comment: You can also set this to State and also you can access wherever it's require it's up to you which approach you want to apply in you app